# How to add versioning support to Azure File Storage

Tags: azure, version-control, versioning, azure-storage

I have a client using Azure file storage (v1) to host some binary files (images, pdfs, etc) for a web app. I'd like to add versioning support in case files get deleted or overwritten, kind of like AWS S3 has. I know Azure Blob storage's newest version supports soft delete but that is still not enough for my needs and, like I said, they're using File Storage.

How can I add robust versioning support to their Azure File storage. My best thought so far is to use Git LFS, with Git being hosted in VSTS and the versioned files going into another Azure File Storage account. That might require a VM to map the drive and everything. I'm not sure.  Are there any better ways to do this? Will my idea work?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One way you can achieve what you are looking for would be to use share snapshots. Share snapshots are similar to what you might achieve on a Windows volume with VSS, and files will even show up under the "Previous Versions" for a file in Windows when the share is mounted over SMB.

Here are some references on share snapshots:

- https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/files/storage-snapshots-files
- https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/files/storage-how-to-use-files-snapshots

Hope this helps,

Will Gries
Program Manager, Azure Files

Comment: Thanks! This looks like exactly what I need. Too bad its not out of preview yet. :-(  This is for production, so I might have trouble selling the client on it.

Comment: Snapshots have reached general availability! Woo!  https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/announcing-the-general-availability-of-azure-files-share-snapshot/